# How to store/save temporary value and compare?

Tags: java, arrays

```
DatagramSocket clientSocket = new DatagramSocket(10076);
InetAddress IPAddress = InetAddress.getByName("192.168.100.10");
byte[] sendData = new byte[9];
byte[] receiveData = new byte[9];
String sentence = "VDV2bE1";
sendData = sentence.getBytes();
DatagramPacket sendPacket = new DatagramPacket(sendData, sendData.length, IPAddress, 10076);
clientSocket.send(sendPacket);
DatagramPacket receivePacket = new DatagramPacket(receiveData, receiveData.length);
clientSocket.receive(receivePacket);
clientSocket.close();

  UDP strToHex = new UDP();
  String result = new String(receivePacket.getData());
  String hex = strToHex.convertStringToHex(result);  
  String cut = hex.substring(10);

  String A = cut.substring(0, 2);
  String B = cut.substring(2, 4);
  String C = cut.substring(4, 6);
  String D = cut.substring(6, 8);

  int cvA = Integer.parseInt(A);    
  int cvB = Integer.parseInt(B);
  int cvC = Integer.parseInt(C);
  int cvD = Integer.parseInt(D);

  int calcA = (cvA - 30)*16;
  int calcB = (cvB - 30);
  int calcC = (cvC - 30)*16;
  int calcD = (cvD - 30);

  int PassIN = calcA + calcB;
  int PassOUT = calcC + calcD;

  int LPassIN = 0;
  int LPassOUT = 0;
  int tempIN;
  int tempOUT;


  if (LPassIN == 0)
  {
      tempIN = LPassIN + PassIN;
  } else if (LPassIN == PassIN)
  {
      tempIN = LPassIN ;
  } else if (LPassIN != PassIN);
  {
      tempIN = PassIN;
  }

  if (LPassOUT == 0)
  {
      tempOUT = LPassOUT + PassOUT;
  } else if (LPassOUT == PassOUT)
  {
      tempOUT = LPassOUT ;
  } else if (LPassOUT != PassOUT);
  {
      tempOUT = PassOUT;
  }

  System.out.println(tempIN);
  System.out.println(tempOUT);
```

I'm trying to temporarily save/store the value in the `PassIN` into `LPassIN`
and then I'm going to compare both, if they are different then save into LPassIN and print the new value, else print old value.

Comment: can't see `tempPassIN`, can you clarify the question please?

Comment: ermm i dont know how to explain, tempPassIN not present because i deleted it, the current code so far functional but i'm trying to improve it by add comparison

Comment: edit your question, please, we can't help you as is

Comment: ok i try, how about now?

Comment: so you want to initialize LPassIN with the value you have in PassIN (currently you initialize it with value 0), than you want to compare them and if they are different you want to save the value of PassIN into LPassIN and print the value of PassIN, else (they are equal) print anyway the value of PassIN. Am I correct?

Comment: yes kinda like that, just that LPassIN start with value 0

Comment: the LPassIN have value 0 and then a value inserted into PassIN. From that i compare them,if different save into LPassLN (print value).Then another new value insert into PassIN,compare again,if different save into LPassIN and print PassIN, else (if equal) print value of LPassIN

Answer (score 0):

this should work

```
if (LPassIN != PassIN);
{
    LPassIN = PassIN;
}
System.out.println(LPassIN);
```